# React auto scroll to bottom on a chat container

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a chat page using react. And I have obviously come to a problem where the chat bubbles container doesn't automatically scroll down to bottom on componentDidMount and Update.

I was looking through the previous Q&A but couldn't find any decent solution.

Here is the comoponent.

```
// renders the text form and all the messages

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { convo } from '../../data/convo';
import SingleMessage from '../singleMessage/singleMessage';
import StyledForm from './styles';
import moment from 'moment';

class MessageRoom extends Component {

//convo contains the messages
    state = {
        convo,
        message: ''
    };

    handleChange = e => {
        const message = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ message });
    };

    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.state.message) {
            const text = {
                message: this.state.message,
                owner: 0,
                date: moment()
            };

            this.setState({ convo: [...this.state.convo, text], message: '' });
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <StyledForm>
                <div className="messages">
                    {this.state.convo.map(text => (
                        <SingleMessage text={text} key={text.date} />
                    ))}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <form
                        onSubmit={e => {
                            this.onSubmit(e);
                        }}
                    >
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Type a message"
                            value={this.state.message}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                        <button type="submit"> Send </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </StyledForm>
        );
    }
}

export default MessageRoom;
```

So please help a brother out!

Comment: Put a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref) on your container, and scroll it to the bottom in `componentDidMount`. `this.ref.current.scrollTop = this.ref.current.scrollHeight;`

Comment: can you send a snippet or something!

Comment: And what does current stand for?

Answer (score 5):

```js
// renders the text form and all the messages

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { convo } from '../../data/convo';
import SingleMessage from '../singleMessage/singleMessage';
import StyledForm from './styles';
import moment from 'moment';

class MessageRoom extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
   convo,
   message: ''
  };

  this.mesRef = React.createRef();
 }

 componentDidMount() {
  this.scrollToBottom();
 }

 scrollToBottom = () => {
  this.mesRef.current.scrollTop = this.mesRef.current.scrollHeight;
 };

 handleChange = e => {
  const message = e.target.value;
  this.setState({ message });
 };

 onSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (this.state.message) {
   const text = {
    message: this.state.message,
    owner: 0,
    date: moment()
   };

   this.setState(
    { convo: [...this.state.convo, text], message: '' },
    () => {
     this.scrollToBottom();
    }
   );
  }
 };

 render() {
  return (
   <StyledForm>
    <div className="messages" ref={this.mesRef}>
     {this.state.convo.map(text => (
      <SingleMessage text={text} key={text.date} />
     ))}
    </div>
    <div>
     <form
      onSubmit={e => {
       this.onSubmit(e);
      }}
     >
      <input
       type="text"
       placeholder="Type a message"
       value={this.state.message}
       onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
      <button type="submit"> Send </button>
     </form>
    </div>
   </StyledForm>
  );
 }
}

export default MessageRoom;
```

updated the code to the new ref usage.

Comment: Note that [string refs are deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs) and likely to be removed in future react versions.

Answer (score -1):

There is a very simple way to achieve it some css trick

Wrap Html into parent div for message

```
<div className="message-holder">
    <div className="message"> //state all message
       ...text goes here
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.message-holder{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   //if required overflow to scroll add below css
  overflow-y:scroll
  max-height: //whatever is required
}
.message{
   //css style goes here
}
</style>
```

Have question ping me

Comment: This only anchors the message-holder element to the bottom of the page. It will not automatically scroll as messages are added inside the message-holder, which is what the OP is requesting.